# How to scroll browser to desired element by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, browser

The question is simple.

How to scroll browser to desired element or desired position by javascript?

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To an element :

```
document.getElementById('id').scrollIntoView();
```

[Has cross browser support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_cssom.html#t23) and probably the easiest way to do it ....

or to a specific position :

```
window.scroll(x,y);
```

[Docs for `window.scroll()` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.scroll)

Answer (score 1):

```
//Finds y value of given object
function findPos(obj) {
    var curtop = 0;
    if (obj.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
    return [curtop];
    }
}
//Get object
var SupportDiv = document.getElementById('customer_info');

//Scroll to location of SupportDiv on load
window.scroll(0,findPos(SupportDiv));
```

Comment: Any idea why it's not always working on android mobile devices?