# Get Y position of an element in an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I think this has been asked already, I have an iframe page where we have nearly 10 textfield's, whenever the user taps on any one of the textfield, I would like to know the Y position in that page.
Is that possible?

Comment: Is the content within the iframe on the same domain? Secondly, what have you tried already? Can you provide any examples?

Comment: Are both files on the same server/domain?

Comment: @Lewis, yes it is in the same domain. I was trying in the actual code, didn't have any example to post it here, sorry.

Comment: I tried these links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007530/how-do-i-scroll-to-an-element-using-javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880443/how-to-scroll-browser-to-desired-element-by-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is untested, but should point you in the right direction.

**jQuery**

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
      var iframe = $('iframe');
      var inputs = iframe.find('input');

      $.each(inputs, function(){
        $(this).click(function(){
          console.log($(this).offset().top));
        })
      })
    })
```

**Vanilla Javascript**

Updated as per comment. Also untested.

*Give your iframe an ID to make it easier to target, then:*

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');
var inputs = Array.prototype.slice.call(iframe.getElementsByTagName('input'));

inputs.forEach(function(input,i){
  input.addEventListener('click', function(){
    console.log(this.getBoundingClientRect().top;
  })
})
```

Comment: Am little amatuer in jQuery, is this possible in Javascript ?

Answer (score 0):

If both, the main window and the iframe content are within the same protocol/domain, then you can directly access the iframe's contentBody and get the scrollTop position of the input field.

For instance:

```
var y = $('iframe').contents().find('#myInputField').offset().top;
```